# Password is not taking after waking up from sleep in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, linux-headers

When the screen is locked in Ubuntu or I manually lock using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> it gets the lock. the question is when I switch on the laptop password is not taking it shows invalid password. I have to go to switch user then it is taking password correctly.

So for the same user, the password is invalid after suspend, but by going to 'switch user' and selecting the same user, the same password is valid.

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you using? What is the desktop environment and session manager?

Comment: 14.04 ubuntu metacity

Comment: Can anyone know about this  issue